# BRM OPCODE for extracting purchased product details

Tags: oracle, opcode

Does anyone know what BRM OPCODE i can use to extract purchased products event? In other words, Im trying to find an opcode which takes a certain input field like `PIN_FLD_NAME`, `PIN_FLD_PLAN_OBJ` or `PIN_FLD_DEAL_OBJ` and gives me a list of outputs which includes a field which tells me where the product was purchased from.

Currently, I am using `SUBSCRIPTION_READ_ACCT_PRODUCTS`, which gives me and output list which includes fields like `PIN_FLD_NAME`, `PIN_FLD_PLAN_OBJ` and `PIN_FLD_DEAL_OBJ` etc. 
Kindly, help me out here please.

Answer (score 0):

`/event` has a connection to `/purchased_product`, and `/purchased_product` has a connection to `/deal`. Therefore, it's possible to use `PCM_OP_SEARCH` (or `PCM_OP_GLOBAL_SEARCH`), with input flist such as this:

```
0 PIN_FLD_POID                 POID [0] 0.0.0.1 /search 0 0
0 PIN_FLD_FLAGS                 INT [0] 0
0 PIN_FLD_TEMPLATE              STR [0] "select X from /event 1, /purchased_product 2, /deal 3 where 1.F1 = 2.F2 and 2.F3 = 3.F4 and 3.F5 = V5 "
0 PIN_FLD_RESULTS             ARRAY [*] NULL
0 PIN_FLD_ARGS                ARRAY [1]
1     PIN_FLD_BAL_IMPACTS     ARRAY [*]
2         PIN_FLD_OFFERING_OBJ POID [0] NULL poid
0 PIN_FLD_ARGS                ARRAY [2]
1     PIN_FLD_POID             POID [0] NULL poid
0 PIN_FLD_ARGS                ARRAY [3]
1     PIN_FLD_DEAL_OBJ         POID [0] NULL poid
0 PIN_FLD_ARGS                ARRAY [4]
1     PIN_FLD_POID             POID [0] NULL poid
0 PIN_FLD_ARGS                ARRAY [5]
1     PIN_FLD_NAME              STR [0] "value"
```

You can replace `/purchased_product` with `/purchased_discount`, if needed.

Answer (score 0):

Using service obj array -- you will get all details for all deals and they will contain Product and purchase product pid.

`PCM_OP_SUBSCRIPTION_PURCHASE_DEAL`